# Java log file parser on Windows 2008 is not able to use File.lastModified

Tags: java, log4j, windows-server-2008-r2

We are using a simple log file parser written in Java. Log files are written using `log4j.properties`. The parser relies on `File.lastModified()` to pick the list of files in directory to check if there are any errors in the file.

This was working file until we moved to Windows 2008. After googling, I found [file-date-modified-property-are-not-updating-while-modifying-a-file-without-closing-it](http://blogs.technet.com/b/asiasupp/archive/2010/12/14/file-date-modified-property-are-not-updating-while-modifying-a-file-without-closing-it.aspx) that explained the behavior.

So far I am not able to find any solution to this problem. My alternate option is to store the file size each time my poller check the file and compare the current file size with the previous stored value.

Can anyone suggest a simpler idea?

Comment: I came to know that updating the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate value to 0 can be the solution. But I am not too keen to make this change on Production machine. Does anyone see a problem with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only putting it here to inform others if they face the same problem. In my case it turned out a code issue where handle to the file was not closed properly. I used [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see any unwanted open handles to the file.